# SQL Exercise help needed from sql-ex

Tags: sql

I'm currently doing exercise #6 on `sql-ex`

the question is as follow:

For each maker producing laptops with a hard drive capacity of 10 Gb or higher, find the speed of such laptops. Result set: maker, speed.

The database contains 4 tables

Product(maker, model, type)

Laptop(Model, price, speed, ram, hd, screen)

PC(model, price, speed, ram, hd)

Printer(model,price, color, price)

My answer:

```
SELECT Product.maker,
       Laptop.speed
FROM Product JOIN Laptop
    ON Product.model = Laptop.model
WHERE Laptop.hd >= 10
```

The result is correct but they said this:

> Your query returned the correct dataset on the first (available) database, but it returned incorrect dataset on the second checking database.
>   * Wrong number of records (more by 2)

So I'm wondering what is wrong with my answer.

Hope to get some help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm also wondering what is wrong with your answer, but I think we would need to see the actual data from the two databases to explain the discrepancy.

Comment: ive included the database! hopefully it helps

Comment: You've labelled with MySQL and SQL Server, and I doubt you are using both.  By "database" I mean can you show us the _data_ from the two table, or tables, in question?  Your query looks OK, but maybe the data itself is different, giving you the current result.

Comment: Stop reversing my edits. Dumps of  nonsense don't help. The clarification was asked about the actual **data**, not the assignment or task.

Comment: http://www.sql-ex.ru/learn_exercises.php?LN=6

Comment: No. Not a link to somewhere else. The **actual data**, here, in the question itself. Not the assignment, not a description of the schema or assignment. The **data**. What you've provided is *My answer is a + b = 3, and it should be right, but it's not. Why?*, and we're asking you to provide the definitions of **a** and **b** so we can see whether they add up to 3. (And a hint, even without seeing that data: There's more than one type of JOIN.)

Comment: U must using DISTINCT in SELECT clause. because some laptops may have  same speed.

Answer (score 2):

You must add a `DISTINCT` in the `SELECT` clause, because some laptops may have same speed:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Product.maker,
                Laptop.speed
FROM Product JOIN Laptop
    ON Product.model = Laptop.model
WHERE Laptop.hd >= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to specify:

```
SELECT Product.maker
,Laptop.speed
FROM Product JOIN Laptop
ON Product.model = Laptop.model
WHERE Laptop.hd >= 10
AND Type = 'Laptop'
```